# Image does not work when oneboxed?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

Images are instantly rendered to the browser when properly sent on the chat, however if you send a oneboxed image, it will not render as it would normally.

For instance the below will work as expected:

```
http://site/image_with_proper_file_extension
```

While this one:

```
[http://site/image_with_proper_file_extension](http://site/some_other_link/)
```

Or this one:

```
[![description](http://site/image_with_proper_file_extension)](http://site/some_other_link/)
```

Or this one:

```
[![description][1]](http://site/some_other_link/) [1] http://site/image_with_proper_file_extension
```

Will show you the image link rather than an image. The link will be shown as expected regardless, at least on the first example.

Sample image working:

[image: desc]

Comment: Image which is a link is not "oneboxed". Looks like you confuse some terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chat does not support displaying images in those fashions. Your *only* option to display an image is to post just the image URL or (if it's a weird image link) the URL preceded *solely* with an exclamation point (which explicitly tells the chat client to treat the URL as an image URL).

From the [Chat FAQ](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#formatting):

> Some links will be automatically inlined ***if posted on a single line by themselves***, such as:
>
> - Stack Exchange questions, answers, and users
> - Chat messages and rooms
> - **Images**
> - Wikipedia pages
> - Amazon products
> - Youtube videos
> - Twitter messages
> - Github gists

Comment: FWIW I tried to answer your question solely on the examples you provided. I don't really know what you mean by "send a oneboxed image" - images *get* oneboxed if sent by themselves.

Comment: But `[text](link)` does work and there is nothing saying that `[image](link)` shouldn't once they are both supported

Comment: I was under the understanding that `[image](link)` is a oneboxed? kindly reword on how I should call if its not.

Comment: The `[description](url)` wouldn't even show an image normally on-site, in the comments or in a post. That is and always has been the syntax for displaying a link, not an image. Chat definitely would not even look at that URL to try and figure out if it's an image or not, because that's not the syntax for it.

Comment: It does show but the code is slight different. @animuson I have updated the question with a linked image.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're saying. There is no image syntax for chat. The `![description](url)` syntax you normally would use for images **simply does not work** in chat rooms. You can't use it. Your only option to get an image to display is to paste the URL *by itself* into a message.

Comment: Well it just looked to me that it would appear to be a bug since I can use the very same syntax and not get the same result on the chat.